# Are the exceptions listed in the System.IO Namespace documentation the only exceptions that can be thrown when using methods from this namespace

Tags: .net

Can I assume, if looking at the .NET documentation of System.IO, that exceptions listed there are the only ones that can be thrown by methods in this namespace and that other exception that might occur, but not documented in this namespace, are inner exceptions of the documented exceptions?

I have a feeling this question might be asked before, but I could not find the answer to it. The question is also related to other namespaces in the .NET documentation.

Comment: Why is it important? You can't be sure because it's documentation that might be outdated. So don't rely on it

Comment: If you assume the documentation is always up to date, it could be a design choice in .NET only to throw the exceptions listed in the documentation.

Comment: Both assumptions are hypothetical, you can't and should not rely on it. Catch `Exception` to be sure.

Comment: What documentation?

Comment: Of course, Catch Exception is what I do use, because you never know what can happen. Nevertheless it could be a design choice in a library or namespace to say: these are the exceptions that are thrown and we will document these exceptions and other exceptions are part of the inner exceptions. So I was interesting to learn if there is such a design choice in for example the System.IO namespace?

Comment: This documentation for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io